Python bytecode, does compare_op pop the stack?
I'm working with the following bytecode:
  6          10 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             12 LOAD_CONST               3 (255)
             14 COMPARE_OP               2 (<)
             18 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       27 (to 74)

LOAD_FAST pushes the value for x (zero in this case) onto the stack.  LOAD_CONST pushes the value of 255 onto the stack.  I cannot find documentation regarding what the less than COMPARE_OP does with the stack although the Documentation for the POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE states that

If STACK[-1] is false, increments the bytecode counter by delta. STACK[-1] is popped.

What happens with the stack when the COMPARE_OP is executed?

The default expectation for bytecode operations is that they pop their operands, and push their result.  The documentation only seems to explicitly mention exceptions to that rule.

@jasonharper, agreed.  And if the result is at STACK[-1], what is on the top of the stack?

STACK[-1] is the top of the stack.  Or were you asking what the exact value pushed by COMPARE_OP is?  It's whatever is returned by the appropriate magic method (.__lt__(), in this case) - usually a boolean, but can be something else if that makes sense for a particular type of object.  For example, comparing Numpy arrays returns an array of booleans with individual comparison results, since there's no particularly good way to define whether one entire array is lesser or greater than another.

So it is.  It was second from the top in some other documentation.  I think it's safe to assume that both initial values are popped and a 1 (true) or 0 (false) is pushed back.  This value is then popped when the jump occurs leaving the stack in whatever state it was in prior to those four lines.

I was going to suggest "look at the value stack", but that turns out to be difficult.

@chepner, agreed.  I would have thought a simple stack dump would be possible but it's not.

@jasonharper is correct.  Bench testing strongly suggests that the COMPARE_OP pops the top two values and pushes a boolean as the result.  The POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE pops the boolean and then executes the conditional jump.  If the value popped is TRUE then no operation is performed.  After those four lines execute the stack is in the same condition as it was before those lines were executed.  Thanks.
